# Maintain the aspect ratio of a div with CSS

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, aspect-ratio

I want to create a responsive `div` that can change its width/height as the window's width changes.

Are there any CSS rules that would allow the height to change according to the width, **while maintaining its aspect ratio**?

I know I can do this via JavaScript, but I would prefer using only CSS.

[image: div keeping aspect ratio according to width of window]

Comment: For future people coming here: The accepted answer is antiquated and mentions ``padding-bottom``. Things changed and ``aspect-ratio`` is now the way to go. Ex.: ``aspect-ratio: 4 / 3;``

Answer (score 1564, accepted):

Just create a wrapper `<div>` with a percentage value for `padding-bottom`, like this:

```css
.demoWrapper {
  padding: 10px;
  background: white;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  resize: horizontal;
  border: 1px dashed;
  overflow: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: calc(100vh - 16px);
}

div {
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 75%;
  background: gold; /** <-- For the demo **/
}
```

```html
<div class="demoWrapper">
  <div></div>
</div>
```

It will result in a `<div>` with height equal to 75% of the width of its container (a 4:3 aspect ratio).

This relies on the fact that for padding :

> The percentage is calculated with respect to the **width** of the generated box's containing block [...]  (source: [w3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/box.html#padding-properties), emphasis mine)

Padding-bottom values for other aspect ratios and 100% width :

```
aspect ratio  | padding-bottom value
--------------|----------------------
    16:9      |       56.25%
    4:3       |       75%
    3:2       |       66.66%
    8:5       |       62.5%
```

---

**Placing content in the div :**

In order to keep the aspect ratio of the div and prevent its content from stretching it, you need to add an absolutely positioned child and stretch it to the edges of the wrapper with:

```css
div.stretchy-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

div.stretchy-wrapper > div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
}
```

[Here's a **demo**](http://dabblet.com/gist/2590942) and another more in depth [demo](http://jsbin.com/vatuqiyebu/edit)

Comment: @schellmax, it is because padding % is calculated relative to the current element's width, where as height % is calculated relative to the parent element's height.  Furthermore, absolute positions are calculated relative to the outside container of an element, which includes the padding area.  For more information Google "CSS Box Model"

Comment: This does not seem to work in a nested fashion. It works at the first level, but when trying to do the same thing inside of the div maintaining aspect ratio, the padding-bottom percentage seems to get applied to the width of the parent. [here is an example](http://jsfiddle.net/misterparker/7ABCw/) where the .stretchy-wrap.onethird padding-bottom of 25% is actually 25% of the parent width. Can someone explain this?

Answer (score 708):

There are **several ways to specify a fixed aspect ratio** on an element like a div, here are 2 of them:

## 1. The `aspect-ratio` CSS property

```css
div {
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
  width: 50%;
  background: teal;
}
```

```html
<div>aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;</div>
```

**This is the most simple and flexible solution**. It directly specifies a fixed width to height (or height to width) aspect ratio for an element. This means you can also specify an aspect ratio according to the elements *height*.
It doesn't rely on the parent width (like the padding technique) or the viewport size (like the following `vw` unit technique) it relies on the element's own width or height [More info on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/aspect-ratio). That is what make it so powerfull compared to other workarounds.

**This is a modern property** (2021). All modern browsers support it, see [caniuse for precise browser support](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_aspect-ratio).

**Here are a few examples with different aspect ratios :**

```css
.ar-1-1  {aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;}
.ar-3-2  {aspect-ratio: 3 / 2;}
.ar-4-3  {aspect-ratio: 4 / 3;}
.ar-16-9 {aspect-ratio: 16 / 9;}
.ar-2-3  {aspect-ratio: 2 / 3;}
.ar-3-4  {aspect-ratio: 3 / 4;}
.ar-9-16 {aspect-ratio: 9 / 16;}


/** For the demo : **/
body {
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  align-items:flex-start;
}
div {
  background: teal;
  width: 23%;
  margin:1%;
  padding:20px 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color:#fff;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="ar-1-1">aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;</div>
<div class="ar-3-2">aspect-ratio: 3 / 2;</div>
<div class="ar-4-3">aspect-ratio: 4 / 3;</div>
<div class="ar-16-9">aspect-ratio: 16 / 9;</div>
<div class="ar-2-3">aspect-ratio: 2 / 3;</div>
<div class="ar-3-4">aspect-ratio: 3 / 4;</div>
<div class="ar-9-16">aspect-ratio: 9 / 16;</div>
```

## 2. Using `vw` units:

You can use `vw` units for both the width and height of the element. This allows the element's aspect ratio to be preserved, **based on the viewport width**.

> vw : 1/100th of the width of the viewport.  [*[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#Viewport-percentage_lengths)*]

Alternatively, you can also use `vh` for viewport height, or even `vmin`/`vmax` to use the lesser/greater of the viewport dimensions (discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23630140/fit-responsive-square-in-viewport-according-to-width-and-height/23631436#23631436)).

**Example: 1:1 aspect ratio**

```css
div {
  width: 20vw;
  height: 20vw;
  background: gold;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

For other aspect ratios, you can use the following table to calculate the value for height according to the width of the element :

```
aspect ratio  |  multiply width by
-----------------------------------
     1:1      |         1
     1:3      |         3
     4:3      |        0.75
    16:9      |       0.5625
```

### Example: 4x4 grid of square divs

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
div {
  width: 23vw;
  height: 23vw;
  margin: 0.5vw auto;
  background: gold;
}
```

```html
<div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
```

Here is a [Fiddle with this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/dAebS/606/) and here is a solution to make a [responsive grid of squares with verticaly and horizontaly centered content](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20456694/1811992).

---

Browser support for vh/vw units is IE9+ see [canIuse for more info](http://caniuse.com/viewport-units)

Comment: While aspect-ratio does live up to its name, I find that it does so by expanding the box around my text rather than re-flowing the text.  The result is a lot of empty space at the bottom rather than a tight fit around the content.  Is there a fix for  that?  Ideally, it would be elastic, too, in case it hits a hard max-width or max-height.  (Better to stretch than clip.)

Answer (score 155):

Use the `aspect-ratio` CSS property

```html
<div class='demo'></div>
```

```
.demo {
  background: black;
  width: 500px;
  aspect-ratio: 4/3;
}
```

Comment: Note: When you only use the width property with 100% as value, this width will be calculated, so that it won't fill the horizontal space. When you want to preserve the 100% width, you have to add both width and height with each 100% set. That way it will work (at least in the latest Chrome it works correctly).

Comment: Overwolf is still using a version of Chromium that does not support `aspec-ratio`. Instead you can use something like `height: calc(100vw * 4 / 3);`

Comment: This appears to repeat (although with more detail) the solution from 2020 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495407/maintain-the-aspect-ratio-of-a-div-with-css/61825062#61825062

Comment: this properties save a dozen lines of code

Answer (score 68):

This answer was written before `aspect-ratio` was implemented in CSS. That's what you should use *today*.

---

**Original answer**

I stumbled upon what I consider [a smart solution](https://codeburst.io/keeping-aspect-ratio-with-html-and-no-padding-tricks-40705656808b) for this problem, using `<svg>` and `display:grid`.

A `display:grid` element allows you to occupy the same space with two (or more) of its children, using the same `grid-area`.
This means means they are all flow content, overlapped, and out of the box **the taller one sets the ratio**.

One of them will be an `<svg>` in charge of setting the ratio. The other, actual content. If actual content is short and never fills up the entire ratio (and you just want it centered in a space with this ratio), simply center it (see first runnable snippet below).

```
<div class="ratio">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 1 1"></svg>
  <div>
    I'm square
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.ratio {
  display: grid;
}
.ratio > * {
  grid-area: 1/1;
}
```

Set `<svg>`s ratio to whatever you want:

- `<svg viewBox="0 0 4 3"></svg>`
- `<svg viewBox="0 0 16 9"></svg>`

```css
.ratio {
  display: grid;
}
.ratio > * {
  grid-area: 1/1;
}

/* below code NOT needed for setting the ratio 
 * I just wanted to mark it visually
 * and center contents
 */
.ratio div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="ratio">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 7 1"></svg>
  <div>
    Fixed ratio 7:1
  </div>
</div>
```

---

If you need a solution where the content element has more content you want confined into a scrollable area with desired ratio, set `position:relative` on the parent and `position:absolute; height:100%; overflow-y: auto;` on the content, allowing the flow content element (the `<svg>`) to set the size, therefore the ratio.

```css
.ratio {
  display: grid;
  position: relative;
}
.ratio > * {
  grid-area: 1/1;
}


.ratio > div {
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  position: absolute;
  
  /* the rest is not needed */
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 0 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="ratio">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 7 2"></svg>
  <div>
    <h1>Fixed ratio 7:2</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. A scelerisque purus semper eget. Sem nulla pharetra diam sit amet nisl suscipit adipiscing bibendum. A cras semper auctor neque vitae tempus quam pellentesque nec. Morbi enim nunc faucibus a pellentesque sit amet porttitor. Arcu odio ut sem nulla. Sed viverra ipsum nunc aliquet bibendum enim facilisis gravida neque. Cras tincidunt lobortis feugiat vivamus at augue eget. Laoreet sit amet cursus sit amet. Amet nulla facilisi morbi tempus iaculis urna id volutpat. Leo in vitae turpis massa sed elementum tempus egestas sed. Egestas integer eget aliquet nibh. Dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit.

<p>Ut aliquam purus sit amet. Eget magna fermentum iaculis eu non diam phasellus vestibulum. Diam in arcu cursus euismod quis viverra nibh. Nullam vehicula ipsum a arcu cursus vitae congue. Vel orci porta non pulvinar neque laoreet suspendisse. At tellus at urna condimentum mattis pellentesque. Tristique senectus et netus et malesuada. Vel pretium lectus quam id leo in. Interdum velit euismod in pellentesque. Velit euismod in pellentesque massa placerat duis. Vitae suscipit tellus mauris a diam maecenas sed enim.

<p>Mauris a diam maecenas sed enim ut sem. In hendrerit gravida rutrum quisque. Amet dictum sit amet justo donec enim diam. Diam vulputate ut pharetra sit amet aliquam id. Urna porttitor rhoncus dolor purus non enim praesent. Purus in massa tempor nec feugiat nisl pretium. Sagittis vitae et leo duis ut. Facilisi nullam vehicula ipsum a arcu cursus vitae congue mauris. Volutpat odio facilisis mauris sit amet massa vitae tortor condimentum. Aliquam purus sit amet luctus venenatis lectus magna. Sit amet purus gravida quis blandit turpis. Enim eu turpis egestas pretium aenean. Consequat mauris nunc congue nisi. Nunc sed id semper risus in hendrerit gravida rutrum. Ante metus dictum at tempor. Blandit massa enim nec dui nunc mattis enim ut.
  </div>
</div>
```

---

As @emjay noted in a comment below, the ratio svg can be placed in one of the parent's pseudo-elements, as long as it's properly encoded:

```css
.three-squares {
  display: grid;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.three-squares > *, .three-squares:before {
  grid-area: 1/1;
}

.three-squares:before {
  content: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 3 1'%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  line-height: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="three-squares">  
  <div>I'm 3:1</div>
</div>
```

When used inside a pseudo-element, the `<svg>` becomes a *replaced element* which, by default, sits on a baseline of variable height (`4px` in Chrome, `3.5px` in Firefox). The height of the baseline varies according to `line-height`, which is why we need to set `line-height: 0` on the pseudo to get an accurate ratio. More details [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1179090).

---

I personally prefer the version where the `<svg>` is placed in markup, as I can have a single class (`.ratio`) dealing with containers of various ratios (as opposed to having a class for each individual ratio I might need).

Answer (score 29):

I've found a way to do this using CSS, but you have to be careful as it may change depending on the flow of your own web site.  I've done it in order to embed video with a constant aspect ratio within a fluid width portion of my web site.

Say you have an embedded video like this:

```
<object>
     <param ... /><param ... />...
     <embed src="..." ...</embed>
</object>
```

You could then place this all inside a div with a "video" class.  This video class will probably be the fluid element in your website such that, by itself, it has no direct height constraints, but when you resize the browser it will change in width according to the flow of the web site.  This would be the element you are probably trying to get your embedded video in while maintaining a certain aspect ratio of the video.

In order to do this, I put an image before the embedded object within the "video" class div.

!!! The important part is that the image has the correct aspect ratio you wish to maintain.  Also, make sure the size of the image is AT LEAST as big as the smallest you expect the video (or whatever you are maintaining the A.R. of) to get based on your layout.  This will avoid any potential issues in the resolution of the image when it is percentage-resized.  For example, if you wanted to maintain an aspect ratio of 3:2, don't just use a 3px by 2px image.  It may work under some circumstances, but I haven't tested it, and it would probably be a good idea to avoid.

You should probably already have a minimum width like this defined for fluid elements of your web site.  If not, it is a good idea to do so in order to avoid chopping elements off or having overlap when the browser window gets too small.  It is better to have a scroll bar at some point.  The smallest in width a web page should get is somewhere around ~600px (including any fixed width columns) because screen resolutions don't come smaller unless you are dealing with phone-friendly sites. !!!

I use a completely transparent png but I don't really think it ends up mattering if you do it right. Like this:

```
<div class="video">
     <img class="maintainaspectratio" src="maintainaspectratio.png" />
     <object>
          <param ... /><param ... />...
          <embed src="..." ...</embed>
     </object>
</div>
```

Now you should be able to add CSS similar to the following:

```
div.video { ...; position: relative; }
div.video img.maintainaspectratio { width: 100%; }
div.video object { position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; }
div.video embed {width: 100%; height: 100%; }
```

Make sure you also remove any explicit height or width declaration within the object and embed tags that usually come with copy/pasted embed code.

The way it works depends on the position properties of the video class element and the item you want have maintain a certain aspect ratio.  It takes advantage of the way an image will maintain its proper aspect ratio when resized in an element.  It tells whatever else is in video class element to take full-advantage of the real estate provided by the dynamic image by forcing its width/height to 100% of the video class element being adjusted by the image.

Pretty cool, eh?

You might have to play around with it a bit to get it to work with your own design, but this actually works surprisingly well for me.  The general concept is there.

Answer (score 20):

Elliot inspired me to this solution - thanks:

`aspectratio.png` is a completely transparent PNG-file with the size of your preferred aspect-ratio, in my case 30x10 pixels.

#### HTML

```
<div class="eyecatcher">
  <img src="/img/aspectratio.png"/>
</div>
```

#### CSS3

```
.eyecatcher img {
  width: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-image: url(../img/autoresized-picture.jpg);
}
```

**Please note:** `background-size` is a css3-feature which might not work with your target-browsers. You may check interoperability (f.e. on [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=background-size)).

Answer (score 18):

As @web-tiki already show a way to use `vh`/`vw`, I also need a way to center in the screen, here is a snippet code for **9:16** portrait.

```
.container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: calc(100vw * 16 / 9);
  transform: translateY(calc((100vw * 16 / 9 - 100vh) / -2));
}
```

`translateY` will keep this center in the screen. `calc(100vw * 16 / 9)` is expected height for 9/16.`(100vw * 16 / 9 - 100vh)` is overflow height, so, pull up `overflow height/2` will keep it center on screen.

For landscape, and keep **16:9**, you show use

```
.container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: calc(100vw * 9 / 16);
  transform: translateY(calc((100vw * 9 / 16 - 100vh) / -2));
}
```

The ratio 9/16 is ease to change, no need to predefined `100:56.25` or `100:75`.If you want to ensure height first, you should switch width and height, e.g. `height:100vh;width: calc(100vh * 9 / 16)` for 9:16 portrait.

If you want to adapted for different screen size, you may also interest

- [background-size](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size#cover) cover/contain

  - Above style is similar to contain, depends on width:height ratio.
- [object-fit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit#)

  - cover/contain for img/video tag
- `@media (orientation: portrait)`/`@media (orientation: landscape)`

  - Media query for `portrait`/`landscape` to change the ratio.

Answer (score 17):

As stated in [here on w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_padding.asp) and somewhat reiterated in this [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10441480/3786856), padding values as percentages (emphasis mine):

> Specifies the padding in percent of the width of the **containing element**

Ergo, a correct example of a responsive DIV that keeps a 16:9 aspect ratio is as follows:

CSS

```
.parent {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
.child {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: calc(100% * 9 / 16);
}
.child > div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
        <div>Aspect is kept when resizing</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Demo on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/marcandrews/qaez1mLw/)

Answer (score 16):

To add to Web_Designer's answer, the `<div>` will have a height (entirely made up of bottom padding) of 75% of the width of it's **containing element**. Here's a good summary: http://mattsnider.com/css-using-percent-for-margin-and-padding/. I'm not sure why this should be so, but that's how it is.

If you want your div to be a width other than 100%, you need another wrapping div on which to set the width:

```
div.ar-outer{
    width: 60%; /* container; whatever width you want */
    margin: 0 auto; /* centered if you like */
}
div.ar {
    width:100%; /* 100% of width of container */
    padding-bottom: 75%; /* 75% of width of container */
    position:relative;
}
div.ar-inner {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
}
```

I used something similar to Elliot's image trick recently to allow me to use CSS media queries to serve a different logo file depending on device resolution, but still scale proportionally as an `<img>` would naturally do (I set the logo as background image to a transparent .png with the correct aspect ratio). But Web_Designer's solution would save me an http request.

Comment: Great solution. In my case I know the "natural" image size when placing it to DOM and I need to have an image placeholder with proper height to prevent further scrolling once the browser loads the images. In .ar-outer I have the image width in pixels, in .ar I have padding-bottom calculated from real image aspect ratio. Instead of ar-inner I have the image itself (<img>). However I had to set width to 100% instead of setting top, bottom, left and right. When I set maxWidth to ar-outer, the image scales nicely when parent is small, but doesn't scale to bigger size than its natural size.

Answer (score 16):

Use the CSS `aspect-ratio` property

https://caniuse.com/#search=aspect-ratio

https://web.dev/aspect-ratio/

If you are interested how to use it - take a look at the below super easy example

```
.yourClass {
   aspect-ratio: 4/3;
}
```

Answer (score 14):

This is an improvement on [web_designer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495407/maintain-the-aspect-ratio-of-a-div-with-css/10441480#10441480):

- Uses pseudo elements instead of wrapper divs
- **The aspect ratio is based on the width of the box instead of its parent**
- The box will stretch vertically when the content becomes taller

```css
.box {
  margin-top: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  background-color: #CCC;
}

.fixed-ar::before {
  content: "";
  float: left;
  width: 1px;
  margin-left: -1px;
}
.fixed-ar::after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.fixed-ar-16-9::before {
  padding-top: 56.25%;
}
.fixed-ar-3-2::before {
  padding-top: 66.66%;
}
.fixed-ar-4-3::before {
  padding-top: 75%;
}
.fixed-ar-1-1::before {
  padding-top: 100%;
}

.width-50 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
}
.width-20 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box fixed-ar fixed-ar-16-9">16:9 full width</div>
<hr>
<div class="box fixed-ar fixed-ar-16-9 width-50">16:9</div>
<hr>
<div class="box fixed-ar fixed-ar-16-9 width-20">16:9</div>
<div class="box fixed-ar fixed-ar-3-2 width-20">3:2</div>
<div class="box fixed-ar fixed-ar-4-3 width-20">4:3</div>
<div class="box fixed-ar fixed-ar-1-1 width-20">1:1</div>
<hr>
<div class="box fixed-ar fixed-ar-16-9 width-20">16:9</div>
<div class="box fixed-ar fixed-ar-16-9 width-50">16:9</div>
```

Answer (score 9):

Here's how I do it :

```
[data-aspect-ratio] {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

[data-aspect-ratio]:before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
}

[data-aspect-ratio] > * {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
[data-aspect-ratio="3:1"]:before {
    padding-top: 33.33%;
}
[data-aspect-ratio="2:1"]:before {
    padding-top: 50%;
}
[data-aspect-ratio="16:9"]:before {
    padding-top: 56.25%;
}
[data-aspect-ratio="3:2"]:before {
    padding-top: 66.66%;
}
[data-aspect-ratio="4:3"]:before {
    padding-top: 75%;
}
[data-aspect-ratio="1:1"]:before {
    padding-top: 100%;
}
[data-aspect-ratio="3:4"]:before {
    padding-top: 133.33%;
}
[data-aspect-ratio="2:3"]:before {
    padding-top: 150%;
}
[data-aspect-ratio="9:16"]:before {
    padding-top: 177.77%;
}
[data-aspect-ratio="1:2"]:before {
    padding-top: 200%;
}
[data-aspect-ratio="1:3"]:before {
    padding-top: 300%;
}
```

For example :

```
<div data-aspect-ratio="16:9"><iframe ...></iframe></div>
```

[source](http://zzzzbov.com/blag/scalable-videos-with-aspect-ratio)

Comment: Just FYI...You can do this exact thing (using attribute selectors) in exactly the same amount of lines using plain CSS. The `[data-aspect-ratio]` attribute selector is available to you in CSS.

Answer (score 9):

You can use an svg. Make the container/wrapper position relative, put the svg first as staticly positioned and then put absolutely positioned content (top: 0; left:0; right:0; bottom:0;)

Example with 16:9 proportions:

image.svg: (can be inlined in src)

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 16 9" width="16" height="9"/>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  position: relative;
}
.content {
  position: absolute;
  top:0; left:0; right:0; bottom:0;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <img style="width: 100%" src="image.svg" />
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

Note that inline svg doesn't seem to work, but you can urlencode the svg and embed it in img src attribute like this:

```
<img src="data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%2016%209%22%20width%3D%2216%22%20height%3D%229%22%2F%3E" style="width: 100%;" />
```

Answer (score 8):

Basing on your solutions I've made some trick:

When you use it, your HTML will be only

```
<div data-keep-ratio="75%">
    <div>Main content</div>
</div>
```

To use it this way make:
CSS:

```
*[data-keep-ratio] {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
*[data-keep-ratio] > * {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

and js (jQuery)

```
$('*[data-keep-ratio]').each(function(){ 
    var ratio = $(this).data('keep-ratio');
    $(this).css('padding-bottom', ratio);
});
```

And having this you just set attr `data-keep-ratio` to height/width and that's it.

Answer (score 8):

### Using Grid and padding of pseudo element

I have found some more fresh way to solve this case. This solution is a descendant of a any `padding-bottom` method, but without any `position: absolute` children, just using `display: grid;` and pseudo element.

Here we have `.ratio::before` with good old `padding-bottom: XX%` and `grid-area: 1 / 1 / 1 / 1;`, which forces the pseudo element to keep the position in grid. Although here we have `width: 0;` to prevent overflowing main element by this one (we cold use `z-index` here, but this one is shorter).

And our main element `.ratio > *:first-child` has the same position as `.ratio::before`, which is `grid-area: 1 / 1 / 1 / 1;`, so they both shares the same grid cell place. Now we can put any content in our div, and the pseudo element is the one who determines the width/height ratio. More about [grid-area](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-area).

```css
.ratio {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  max-width: 200px; /* just for instance, can be 100% and depends on parent */  
}

.ratio::before {
  content: '';
  width: 0;
  padding-bottom: calc(100% / (16/9)); /* here you can place any ratio */
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 1 / 1;
}

.ratio>*:first-child {
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 1 / 1; /* the same as ::before */
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1); /* just for instance */
}
```

```html
<div class="ratio">
  <div>16/9</div>
</div>
```

---

Although you can use CSS val and place you ratio in HTML using `style` attribute. Works with `display: inline-grid` as well.

```css
.ratio {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  width: 200px; /* just for instance, can be 100% and depends on parent */ 
  margin-right: 10px; /* just for instance */
}

.ratio::before {
  content: '';
  width: 0;
  padding-bottom: calc(100% / (var(--r))); /* here you can place any ratio */
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 1 / 1;
}

.ratio>*:first-child {
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 1 / 1; /* the same as ::before */
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1); /* just for instance */
}
```

```html
<div class="ratio" style="--r: 4/3;">
  <div>4/3</div>
</div>

<div class="ratio" style="--r: 16/9;">
  <div>16/9</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7):

While most answers are very cool, most of them require to have an image already sized correctly... Other solutions only work for a width and do not care of the height available, but sometimes you want to fit the content in a certain height too.

I've tried to couple them together to bring a fully portable and re-sizable solution... The trick is to use to auto scaling of an image but use an inline svg element instead of using a pre-rendered image or any form of second HTTP request...

```css
div.holder{
  background-color:red;
  display:inline-block;
  height:100px;
  width:400px;
}
svg, img{
  background-color:blue;
  display:block;
  height:auto;
  width:auto;
  max-width:100%;
  max-height:100%;
}
.content_sizer{
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
  height:100%;
}
.content{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  background-color:rgba(155,255,0,0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="holder">
  <div class="content_sizer">
    <svg width=10000 height=5000 />
    <div class="content">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Notice that I have used big values in the width and height attributes of the SVG, as it needs to be bigger than the maximum expected size as it can only shrink. The example makes the div's ratio 10:5

Answer (score 6):

If you want to fit a square inside the viewport on either portrait or landscape view (as big as possible, but nothing sticking outside), switch between using `vw`/`vh` on orientation `portrait`/`landscape`:

```
@media (orientation:portrait ) {
  .square {
    width :100vw;
    height:100vw;
  }
} 
@media (orientation:landscape) {
  .square {
    width :100vh;
    height:100vh;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can achieve that by using SVG.

It depends on a case, but in some it is really usefull. As an example - you can set `background-image` without setting fixed height or use it to embed youtube `<iframe>` with ratio `16:9` and `position:absolute` etc.

For `3:2` ratio set `viewBox="0 0 3 2"` and so on.

Example:

```css
div{
    background-color:red
}
svg{
    width:100%;
    display:block;
    visibility:hidden
}

.demo-1{width:35%}
.demo-2{width:20%}
```

```html
<div class="demo-1">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 3 2"></svg>
</div>

<hr>

<div class="demo-2">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 3 2"></svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

lets say you have 2 divs the outher div is a container and the inner could be any element that you need to keep its ratio (img or an youtube iframe or whatever )

html looks like this :

```
<div class='container'>
  <div class='element'>
  </div><!-- end of element -->
<div><!-- end of container -->
```

lets say you need to keep the ratio of the "element"
ratio => 4 to 1 or 2 to 1 ...

css looks like this

```
.container{
  position: relative;
  height: 0
  padding-bottom : 75% /* for 4 to 3 ratio */ 25% /* for 4 to 1 ratio ..*/
  
}

.element{
  width : 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute; 
  top : 0 ;
  bottom : 0 ;
  background : red; /* just for illustration */
}
```

padding when specified in % it is calculated based on width not height.
..
so basically you it doesn't matter what your width it height will always be calculated based of that . which will keep the ratio .

Answer (score 5):

I'd like to share my solution, where I have an `img`-tag filling a certain aspect ratio. I couldn't use `background` because of lack of support of the CMS and I'd not prefer to use a style tag like so: `<img style="background:url(...)" />`. Also, the width is 100%, so it doesn't need to be set at a fixed size as in some of the solutions. It will scale responsively!

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 50%;
}

.image-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.image-container::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
}

.image-container img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.ratio-4-3::before {
  padding-top: 75%;
}

.ratio-3-1::before {
  padding-top: calc(100% / 3);
}

.ratio-2-1::before {
  padding-top: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper"> <!-- Just to make things a bit smaller -->
  <p>
  Example of an 4:3 aspect ratio, filled by an image with an 1:1 ratio.
  </p>
  <div class="image-container ratio-4-3"> <!-- Lets go for a 4:3 aspect ratio -->
    <img src="https://placekitten.com/1000/1000/" alt="Kittens!" />
  </div>
  <p>
  Just place other block elements around it; it will work just fine.
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

## A simple way of maintaining the aspect ratio, using the canvas element.

#### Try resizing the div below to see it in action.

For me, this approach worked best, so I am sharing it with others so they can benefit from it as well.

```css
.cont {
  border: 5px solid blue;
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 5px;
  resize: horizontal;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.ratio {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
}

.content {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
  <canvas class="ratio" width="16" height="9"></canvas>
  <div class="content">I am 16:9</div>
</div>
```

## Also works with dynamic height!

```css
.cont {
  border: 5px solid blue;
  position: relative;
  height: 170px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 5px;
  resize: vertical;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block; /* so the div doesn't automatically expand to max width */
}

.ratio {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
}

.content {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
  <canvas class="ratio" width="16" height="9"></canvas>
  <div class="content">I am 16:9</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This answer would benefit from any explanation at all.

Answer (score 3):

Just an idea or a hack.

```css
div {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 10%;
  transition: background-color 0.5s, width 0.5s;
  font-size: 0;
}

div:hover {
  width: 20%;
  background-color: red;
}
  
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <!-- use an image with target aspect ratio. sample is a square -->
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/9OPnZNk.png" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

New in Chrome 88 and soon to follow in other browsers is the new CSS [`aspect-ratio`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/aspect-ratio) property.

> The aspect-ratio  CSS property sets a preferred aspect ratio for the box, which will be used in the calculation of auto sizes and some other layout functions.

[**CSS Tricks Article**](https://css-tricks.com/new-in-chrome-88-aspect-ratio/)

[**More Information**](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/a/aspect-ratio/)

```css
div {
  background: rebeccapurple;
  height:100px;
  margin:1em auto;
}

.square {
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
  }
```

```html
<div class="square">
  
</div>
```

Comment: This appears to repeat (although with more detail) the solution from 2020 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495407/maintain-the-aspect-ratio-of-a-div-with-css/61825062#61825062

Answer (score 3):

CSS has a new property for this: `aspect-ratio`.

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/aspect-ratio

```css
@supports (aspect-ratio: 1 / 1) {
  div {
    aspect-ratio: 16 / 9;
    background-color: orange;
  }  
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 200px"></div>
<hr />
<div style="width: 400px"></div>
<hr />
<div style="height: 50px"></div>
<hr />
<div style="height: 10px"></div>
```

Chrome and Edge have been supporting this fully since V88, and Firefox has been supporting it *behind a flag* since V81 (set `layout.css.aspect-ratio.enabled` to `true` in [about:config](http://about:config)).

For compatibility information, check https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_aspect-ratio

Comment: This appears to repeat (although with more detail) the solution from 2020 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495407/maintain-the-aspect-ratio-of-a-div-with-css/61825062#61825062

Comment: @TylerH What are you trying to say here?

Comment: I thought it was fairly clear, but I'll elaborate: the solution offered here (to use the `aspect-ratio` property) is not novel; the answer I linked to from 2020 also `uses aspect-ratio`. However, the answer I linked to also has little detail in terms of how it might be used, compared to this answer.

Comment: @TylerH So what is the purpose of your comment?

Comment: To serve as a post-it note of useful information for future readers and curators that land on this thread.

Answer (score 3):

The new aspect-ratio tag would be awesome, but it messed up the positioning of my divs.
The traditional solution of padding a wrapper div, works, but only adjusts the size according to the width of the parent or the viewport, which makes it **problematic when the height is the limiting factor**.

I found the `min()` function to be very useful, and adjusted the traditional method like so:

```css
body{
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top right, #FFE6B5, #B3CEBF);
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow-y: hidden; /* this is to avoid scrolling when the height of the viewport is less than what the aspect ratio requires */
}

.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 100vw;
    max-height: 100vh;
}
.sixteen-by-nine.aspect-ratio { 
    padding-bottom: 56.25% /* 9:16 ratio */
}
.content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
    background-color: green
}

.centered {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    height: 100%;
    width: min(177.8vh, 100%); /* this always keeps a 16:9 ratio within the viewport */
    font-size: min(3vh,1.7vw); /* if you are also interested in scaling the font size */
    background-color: blue
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="sixteen-by-nine aspect-ratio"></div>
    <div class="content" >
      <div class="centered">
        <!-- stuff goes here -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

Say that you like to maintain Width: 100px and the Height: 50px (i.e., 2:1) 
Just do this math:

```
.pb-2to1 {
  padding-bottom: calc(50 / 100 * 100%); // i.e., 2:1
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just created a 2:1 div that resized to occupy the full width, but then shrinks the width if it would cause the top or bottom to exceed. But note, this will only work with the size of the window, not the size of the parent.

```
#scene {
    position: relative;
    top: 50vh;
    left: 50vw;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 50vw;
    max-height: 100vh;
    max-width: calc(100vh * 2);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

I'm sure you can work out the correct %'s to use for `4:3` instead of `2:1`.

Answer (score 1):

We solved it like this:

```
.square {
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

see https://jsfiddle.net/r1jL3oqa/1/

Comment: This appears to repeat this solution from 2020 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495407/maintain-the-aspect-ratio-of-a-div-with-css/61825062#61825062

Answer (score 0):

I used a new solution.

```
.squares{
  width: 30vw
  height: 30vw
```

To main aspect ratio

```
.aspect-ratio
  width: 10vw
  height: 10vh
```

However, this is relative to the entire viewport. So, if you need a div that is 30% of the viewport width, you can use 30vw instead, and since you know the width, you reuse them in height using calc and vw unit.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution for maintaining an 16:9 aspect ratio in portrait or landscape on a div with optional fixed margins.

It's a combination of width/height and max-width/max-height properties with vw units.

In this sample, 50px top and bottom margins are added on hover.

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
}

.fixedRatio {
  max-width: 100vw;
  max-height: calc(9 / 16 * 100vw);
  width: calc(16 / 9 * 100vh);
  height: 100vh;
  
  /* DEBUG */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: blue;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-family: 'Arial';
  color: white;
  transition: width 0.5s ease-in-out, height 0.5s ease-in-out; 
}

.fixedRatio:hover {
  width: calc(16 / 9 * (100vh - 100px));
  height: calc(100vh - 100px);
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='fixedRatio'>
    16:9
  </div>
</div>
```

[Demo on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kstruillou/1d5hz9km/8/)

Answer (score 0):

I guess just using rem or em should solve the problem of fixed ratio but wont be hard bound to the screen as `vw` or `vh` or as painfull to use with flexbox as `%` is. Well, none of the answers worked properly for me, and in my case this attended me:

```
<div class="container">
   <div>
   </div>
</div>
```

```
.container {
   height: 100vh;
   width: 100vw;
}
.container div {
   height: 4em;
   width: 3em;
}
```

Or using `rem`. But anyway, any of them should make it.
`rem` uses the default font-size value as `em` use the closest font-size.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your contributions, I am going to add my solution here which I was able to produce mainly by riffing on the accepted answer. The main reason I like this approach is that there is no unnecessary DOM, because I use the `:before` to do the padding dirty work.

```
@card-standard-line-height: 21px;
@card-standard-title-line-height: 22.5px;
@16to9percentage: 56.25%;

.overflow {
  background-color: inherit;
  /* stylelint-disable property-no-unknown */
  box-orient: vertical;
  -moz-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  /* stylelint-enable */
  color: inherit;
  display: box;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  text-overflow: -o-ellipsis-lastline;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  padding: 2rem;
}

.card {
  color: #fff;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  min-width: unset;
  position: relative;
  
  h2 {
    font: 18px / 22.5px bold;
  }
  
  p {
    font: 14px / 21px normal;
  }

  &-16to9 {
    .badge {
      color: white;
      display:flex;
      background-color: red;
      justify-content: baseline;
      padding: 16px 32px 12px 16px;
      position: absolute;
      right: 0;
      top: 16px;
      z-index: 2;
      span {
        font: 14px / 14px bold;
      }
    }
    // look at this https://css-tricks.com/aspect-ratio-boxes/
    .card {
      &_description {
        max-height: @card-standard-line-height * 1;
        // Number of allowable lines in layout
        -webkit-line-clamp: 1;
      }

      &_image,
      &_info {
        bottom: 0;
        height: 100%;
        max-height: 100%;
        min-height: 100%;
        left: 0;
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
        z-index: 0;
      }

      &_info {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: flex-end;
        padding: 24px;
        z-index: 2;
      }

      &_title {
        max-height: @card-standard-title-line-height * 2;
        // Number of allowable lines in layout
        -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
      }
    }

    &:after,
    &:before {
      content: "";
      display: block;
    }

    &:after {
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
      background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 16%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%);
      bottom: 0;
      height: 100%;
      left: 0;
      position: absolute;
      right: 0;
      top: 0;
      z-index: 1;
    }

    &:before {
      padding-bottom: @16to9percentage;
    }
  }
}
```

https://codepen.io/augur/pen/GRNGLZv?editors=0100

Answer (score 0):

Universal solution to work the same way in every padding-bottom compiant browser (this works even in emulated Internet Explorer 5):

```css
#box {
   width: 100%;
   padding-bottom: 75%;
   margin:0px;
   background: lightblue;
   color: #FFF;
   position: relative;
}
#innerContent {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
}
```

```html
<div style="width:25%">
  <div style="padding:15px;background-color:#66F;">
    <div id="box">
      <div id="innerContent">
        aspect ratio 4:3
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
  div {
    --width: 16;
    --height: 9;
    aspect-ratio: var(--width) / var(--height);
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: deeppink;
    color: dodgerblue;
    font: 6rem monospace;
  }
```

```html
<div>16&ratio;9</div>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/aspect-ratio

Comment: Among the 33 answers, some of them very high scored, there is already `aspect-ratio` used. Please [edit] and add an explanation how your solution adds something new or advantageous.

Comment: It uses CSS vars and math